# How to inserted values from a nested dictionary into a database?

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary with this kind of structure:

```
data: {
    movie_1: {
        movie_id: value,
        room:{
            room_name: room_1,
            session:{
                session_1:{
                    id: session_id,
                    type: value
                }
            }
            room_name: room2,
            session:{
                session_1:{
                    id: session_id,
                    type: value
                }
                session_2:{
                    id: session_id,
                    type: value
                }
            }
        }
    }
    movie_2: {
        movie_id: value,
        room:{
            room_name: room_3,
            session:{
                session_4:{
                    id: session_id,
                    type: value
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will have a number of movies. Each movie will be associated with a number of rooms and, each room, will have a number of sessions.

For example:

The `movie_1` will have the `room_1` and `room_2`. 
The `room_1`, has `session_1` and the `room_2` will have `session_1` and `session_2`.

The `movie_2` will have the `room_3` with `session_4`, only.

I want to insert the data of this dictionary into a database, but here is the problem: The number of movies, rooms and sessions varies.

The dictionary could return me 2 movies, with, for example,
4 rooms and 3 session in the first or 1 room with 2 session in the other.

I'm using Postgres and the information from the dictionary will be inserted into the table `session`:

```
CREATE TABLE session (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    movie_id INT NOT NULL,
    theater_id INT NOT NULL,
    type_room VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    session_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Should I break this dictionary into another structure or create a number of for, saving the id into var and then inserting with multiple query?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to map your object to the database representation. Whatever it is, you didn't tell us. Anyway good old for loop to the rescue.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to find out if there is another way to do that. Was looking in some docs but couldn't find anything.
I'll try with for, then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: First thing you should do is to have a database structure developed. What are your tables? How do these tree data map to them?

Comment: If you're using MySQL, you also need a  [python connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/).

Comment: I'll update the question with the db tables

Comment: @GKE, I have everything working, I'm just having problem with this dictionary insertion.
I'll update the question.

Comment: @GKE Not every database is MySQL. They all normally talk [DBI](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/), though.

Comment: freakish said it right, a for loop will suffice.

Comment: @9000 I know not every DB is MySQL, the OP didn't specify, I edited my comment to clear further confusion.

Comment: Updated.
I'm using Postgres.

Comment: So yeah, you just loop over movies, then loop again (nested) over rooms and nest again a loop over sessions. In each step you create a row and write it to database (or perhaps buffer them all and send in one go after processing the input). If however those ids are actually foreign keys then the processing will get more complicated, since referenced objects have to exist before insert (unless you run a transaction with deferred constraints).

Comment: You could look at the `jsonb` column type if you are willing to change the database schema.

Comment: The structure of the data dictionary doesn't look right. The `room_name` and `session` key are duplicated in the nested room dictionary